# Issue with Spring Batch with Java 7

Tags: spring-batch

I am facing problem in running Spring Batch job in Weblogic 12c with JRE 7.

I have following job and step declaration.

```
<bean id="taskletStep" abstract="true"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
</bean>
<bean id="doInit_EDIBase" class="tos.demand.edi.batch.EdiApplyInitBaseTasklet"
    abstract="true" />
<bean id="doInit_EDIApply"
    class="tos.demand.order.edi.tasklet.CreateLansideOrderCommonInitTasklet"
    parent="doInit_EDIBase" />
<bean id="doInit_CreateLandsideOrder"
    class="tos.demand.order.edi.tasklet.CreateLandsideOrderSpecializedInitTasklet" />
        class="tos.appinfra.batchprocessing.jobexecutionmonitor.JobExecutionLifecycleAgent" />
<batch:job id="CreateLandsideOrderBatchJobCoparn" job-repository="jobRepository">
    <batch:description>CreateLandsideOrderBatchJobCoparn</batch:description>
    <batch:step id="doInit_Apply" parent="taskletStep" next="doInit_CreateOrder">
        <batch:tasklet ref="doInit_EDIApply" />
    </batch:step>
     <batch:step id="doInit_CreateOrder" parent="taskletStep">
        <batch:tasklet ref="doInit_CreateLandsideOrder" />
    </batch:step>
    <batch:listeners>
        <batch:listener ref="batchjobExecutionListener" />
    </batch:listeners>
</batch:job>
```

When I run the job CreateLandsideOrderBatchJobCoparn, first step "doInit_Apply" runs successfully but the next step "doInit_CreateOrder" never starts. I get following exception in Spring DB ( Batch Job Instance table)

```
org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecutionException: Flow execution ended unexpectedly
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:141)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:301)
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run   (SimpleJobLauncher.java:134)
at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:48)
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:127)
at tos.appinfra.batchprocessing.domain.JobControllServiceImpl.submitJobToSpring(JobControllServiceImpl.java:164).
```

.........................

When I delete the step "doInit_Apply" and keep only "doInit_CreateOrder", then "doInit_CreateOrder" executes successfully. Only conditional step execution fails.

Also in spite of adding log4j.logger.org.springframework.batch=debug in log4j.properties, I am not getting Spring Batch logging information.

Comment: look like you get a runtime exception at : tos.appinfra.batchprocessing.domain.JobControllServiceImpl.submitJobToSpring.  Can you edit and post the complete stacktrace to see the root cause?